# Extracting an Excel File from a REST API

Tags: jquery, json, xml, rest, api

I have been given the details for a REST API to pull down something that resembles a spreadsheet into Excel.

I have also been given an Endpoint URL and code that resembles the following:

```
    {
     "Name": "*name*",
     "AuthenticationKey": "*key*",
    }
```

I also have received the following information: "Our API currently only supports HTTP Post payload via a Rest client, we currently do not support GET, but you should be able to return the data needed by using a POST."

Through my research I have learned that I need to use JSON/XML/JavaScript/JQuery/AJAX.

I found this: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/vignettes/json-apis.html but I am not really sure where/how to start. I am also not sure which JQuery version to download/how to use it.

My ultimate goal is to be able to use this API to get data in Tableau.

Any insights/guidance/advice will be extremely helpful!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to write a program in C# using System.Net Library to access the REST API and get the service's response.

To process it, I'd use NPOI's library to read the service's response as an Excel file.